# Shorthand for if(x>y) { x=y} in javaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison

Trying to compare 2 integers' values, X and Y. If X is greater than Y, I want to cap off X at Y, like this -

```
if(x>y) {
    x=y;
}
```

Is there a shorthand way to do this (either in pure JavaScript or jQuery)? I was thinking of using a custom function, but wanted to see if something already existed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min):

```
x = Math.min(x, y);
```

Comment: Awesome, will try that out. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

The only I can think of:

```
x>y && (x=y);
```

And fastest in Chrome 22 (thought `if(...)` would be faster): http://jsperf.com/if-min

Comment: For what it's worth, `if` is actually faster with Firefox 16.0.1 on my current machine. So you thought well :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
x = Math.min(x,y);
```

You are welcome!